# Java insert to mySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a mySQL database named Customer that I am trying to insert data from a textfield in a GUI. I ran the code below and in the console it said "Connected Successfully" with no errors. I checked to see if the information had been inserted into the Customer table of my mySQL database and nothing was inserted. Does anyone know why?

```
         button.setOnAction(e -> {


         Connection dbConnection = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

         try {


           Customer cust = new Customer();
          dbConnection = Connect();
            String sql="Insert into CIS3270.Customer(firstName,lastName, email,userNAME,Address,Zip,State,SecurityQ,  Password, ConfirmPassword,SSN)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
            preparedStatement =  dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);


            preparedStatement.setString(1,cust.getFirstName()); 
            preparedStatement.setString(2,cust.getLastName()); 
            preparedStatement.setString(3,cust.getEmail()); 
            preparedStatement.setString(4,cust.getUserNAME()); 
            preparedStatement.setString(5,cust.getAddress());
            preparedStatement.setString(6,cust.getZip()); 
            preparedStatement.setString(7,cust.getState());
            preparedStatement.setString(8,cust.getSecurityQuestion());
            preparedStatement.setString(9,cust.getPassWORD()); 
            preparedStatement.setString(10,cust.getConfirmPassword());
            preparedStatement.setString(11,cust.getSSN()); 

            preparedStatement.executeBatch(); 
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            dbConnection.close(); 
            preparedStatement.close(); 



        LoginScreen loginPage = new LoginScreen();

        loginPage.start(primaryStage);

         }
         catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
         }
    });

       public static Connection Connect() {
       Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://(ip adress):3306/CIS3270", "root", "password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect");
    }
    if (con != null) {
        System.out.println("Connected Successfully");
    }
    return con;
}
```

Comment: Are you tried  commit (dbConnection.commit()) before close()?

Comment: add code of `Connect()`

Answer (score 1):

You have no need for a batch insert since you're inserting a single row.

The reason your code doesn't do anything is because you're executing an empty batch. You need to call `preparedStatement.addBatch()` too. Or just remove that `executeBatch()` call, as you seem to call `executeUpdate()` too.

Comment: Yes, I tried both removing executeBatch() and adding it as well and got the same result - Successful Connection but nothing actually inserted

Comment: Is the code actually executing? Check with logging or debugging first.

Comment: Well, did you try `dbConnection.commit()`, although autocommit should be enabled by default.

Comment: I just added dbConnection.commit() and ran it. When I clicked the button in my GUI, I got an error in my console saying 'cant call commit when autocommit=true. Is this basically saying there is no need to call commit when autocommit is already true?

Comment: I finally got the insert to work (partially). I say partially because every time I insert in eclipse a new row is created on mySQL Workbench, but all of the values are NULL. Are there any suggestions at this point?

Comment: That's expected. You create a new `Customer` object and insert its data in the database. It's going to be just nulls obviously. But at least now you have the insertion working, you'll just need to insert some useful data.

Comment: I figured it out and am actually quite embarrassed. I NEVER PUT THE GET-STRING! it was setting to Null because I never used getString first.